# JavaScript - jQuery $(window) events issue while invoking 2 functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var NavY = $('.header-top').offset().top;

    var stickyNav = function(){        <----------- 1)
        var ScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (ScrollY > NavY) { 
            $('.header').addClass('stick');
            $('.main-left-arrow').addClass('main-left-arrow-disable');
        } else {
            $('.header').removeClass('stick'); 
            $('.main-left-arrow').removeClass('main-left-arrow-disable');
        }
    };

    $(window).scroll(function() {      <---------- 1)
        stickyNav();
    });
    stickyNav();


    var posts = function() {        <------------- 2)
      $('.btn').click(function() {
        var post = $('.status-box').val();
        $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
        $('.status-box').val('');
        $('.counter').text('140');
        $('.btn').addClass('disabled'); 
      });

      $('.status-box').keyup(function() {
        var postLength = $(this).val().length;
        var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
        $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);

        if(charactersLeft < 0) {
          $('.btn').addClass('disabled'); 
        }
        else if(charactersLeft == 140) {
          $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
        }
        else {
          $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
        }
      });

      $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
    }

    $(window).load(function() {     <--------------- 2)
        posts();
    });
    posts();

});
```

I don't know how to invoke `posts();` function. I know that something might be wrong with `$(window).load` , but I don't know what. This first function - `stickyNav();` works fine. And if I'll write it like :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyNav();
    posts();
});
stickyNav();
posts();
```

...**they will both work**, but that will also make the `post();` function dependent on scrolling which I cannot have.

So the second function is just not working at all. I don't understand why.
I'm trying to combine two functions:

First:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var NavY = $('.header-top').offset().top;

    var stickyNav = function(){
        var ScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (ScrollY > NavY) { 
            $('.header').addClass('stick');
            $('.main-left-arrow').addClass('main-left-arrow-disable');
        } else {
            $('.header').removeClass('stick'); 
            $('.main-left-arrow').removeClass('main-left-arrow-disable');
        }
    };

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        stickyNav();
    });
    stickyNav();
});
```

Second:

```
var posts = function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    var post = $('.status-box').val();
    $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
    $('.status-box').val('');
    $('.counter').text('140');
    $('.btn').addClass('disabled'); 
  });

  $('.status-box').keyup(function() {
    var postLength = $(this).val().length;
    var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
    $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);

    if(charactersLeft < 0) {
      $('.btn').addClass('disabled'); 
    }
    else if(charactersLeft == 140) {
      $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
      $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
    }
  });

  $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
}

$(document).ready(posts);
```

They Both work fine in the seperate files. I just want them to work in one js file. And `post()` can be fired on button press.

Comment: please explain what you expect this code to do. Note that `scroll` event fires many times a second while scrolling

Comment: That seems to be somewhat of an urban myth though. Only browsers with smoothscroll or dragging the scrollbar itself will fire a lot of scroll events. Normal 'instantaneous' mousewheel scrolling like on most browser only triggers a single event.

Comment: @Shikkediel hardly a myth  http://jsfiddle.net/vohbo0h6/

Comment: I'm on a Windows 7 machine myself, the fiddle has a very low impact there. Using a flag or switch of sorts is always a good idea of course. For plain correctness, it doesn't matter if it fires 5 or 500 times too many...

Comment: @aksameet when are you trying to fire the posts event? Do you want it to fire on a button press?

Comment: Sorry guys, I din't write that whats wrong is that `post()` never gets called. Only if I put it in the `$(window).scroll` event. I've added more code to the question explaning what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @oceanexplorer yes - on the button press would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on what your are trying to achieve but perhaps try this to get started:

At the moment you have

```
$(window).load(function() {
    posts();
});
```

Which is currently nested inside a

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

My guess is that the $(window).load has already fired before $(document).ready and thus never gets called.

Have a look at this JSFiddle for some working examples that should get you along the right lines.

https://jsfiddle.net/oceanexplorer/b68fu4j7/1/

Comment: No, this doesn't work either. But you might be on the right track here, cause if I put both functions invocation in the $(window).load event - both won't work.

Comment: When you say it isn't working, do the status box key up or button clicks get fired? Put an alert in there to see if they do. Can you edit your answer to add your html?

Comment: @aksameet Please see the updated answer with a JSFiddle which demonstrates some of what you are trying to achieve, all the events are wired correctly and fire as you would expect. https://jsfiddle.net/oceanexplorer/b68fu4j7/1/